# version_compare to check for major and minor versions

Tags: php, version

I would like to have a function like PHP's [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) which let me compare version and consider minor/major version numbers.

My method should look like

```
function my_version_compare($new_version, $old_version, $operator, $only_minor = false){
    ...
    return (bool) $do_update;
}
```

a major version update is from `2.1` to `2.2` for instance while a minor is from `2.1` to `2.1.1`

```
my_version_compare('2.2', '2.1', '>', false); //true
my_version_compare('2.2', '2.1', '>', true); //false
my_version_compare('2.1.1', '2.1', '>', false); //true
my_version_compare('2.1.1', '2.1', '>', true); //true
```

Basically I like to let the users decide if an auto update should be made on minor versions only or in any case

What I currently have works just with `2.x` to `3.x` updates:

```
function my_version_compare($new_version, $old_version, $operator, $only_minor = false){
    if($only_minor){
        return (bool) version_compare($new_version, $old_version, $operator)
                && !version_compare(intval($new_version), intval($old_version), $operator);
    }else{
        return (bool) version_compare($new_version, $old_version, $operator);
    }
}
```

Comment: sure thing! I just thought it would be useful for others. I've added a method I already have

Comment: You see, that's much better! :)

Comment: also I like to do it "the right way". It should work with all formats `version_compare()` can handle and doing it from scratch is often not future proof

Comment: Have you looked into [SemVer](http://semver.org/)? Your versions looks a lot like this scheme. And there's a [library](https://github.com/vierbergenlars/php-semver) for working with it!

Comment: looks a bit complex for my needs. I may go with some custom solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling I came up with this:

```
function my_version_compare($new_version, $old_version, $operator, $only_minor = false){

    $pos = 1; //position to indicate what's a major version (x.[x].x.x = 1)

    if($only_minor){

        //get parts as array and remove trailing zeros
        $new = explode(".", rtrim($new_version, ".0"));
        $old = explode(".", rtrim($old_version, ".0"));

        //check if it's a major version update
        $is_major_update = version_compare($new[$pos], $old[$pos], $operator) || version_compare(intval($new_version), intval($old_version), $operator);

        //check if it's a minor update
        $is_minor_update = (!$is_major_update && version_compare(strstr($new_version, '.'), strstr($old_version, '.'), $operator));

        return $is_minor_update;
    }

    return version_compare($new_version, $old_version, $operator);

}
```

Feel free to improve this snippet!